# Python Import Question

Tags: python

I have a custom package and I am having import problems. The module structure is like this:

```
- BaseModule
    - Exchange
    - Communications
        - DeviceComm
```

I am trying to import the `Exchange` module into the `DeviceComm` module. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Intra-package references](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references):

```
from .. import Exchange
```